# is the given query is valid in sql?

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT account_name ,SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS 'total_balance' 
AND SUM(total_balance) AS 'net_revenue'
FROM transaction
```

I want to find the total balance and the `sum` of the total balance as net revenue and its giving me the following sql error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and sum(total_balance) as 'net_revenue' from transaction' at line 2
```

Comment: In your case `net_revenue` and `total_balance` will be equal because you are not using group by,so whole table will be treated as one group  also in your query you have a typo of using and instead of comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `AND`.

```
SELECT 
    account_name,
    SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS 'total_balance',
    SUM(total_balance) AS 'net_revenue'
FROM transaction
```

**Note:** Although the above query is syntactically valid, `SUM` is a group function and you'll probably need some `GROUP BY` clause to select the `account_name` correctly. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    account_name,
    SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS 'total_balance',
    SUM(total_balance) AS 'net_revenue'
FROM transaction
GROUP BY account_name
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not valid SQL. Use commas to separate columns in the select-list.

```
SELECT account_name ,SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS 'total_balance',
  SUM(total_balance) AS 'net_revenue'
FROM transaction
```

The formation of list like `apples, bananas and plums` is common in natural English language, but not in code.

Answer (score 0):

2 things wrong here:

1. `AND` is a Boolean operator. You need to use commas to separate multiple columns
2. You need to group by the account name to get the computed values by account name.

So change your query to:

```
SELECT account_name, SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS 'total_balance', SUM(total_balance) AS 'net_revenue'
FROM transaction
GROUP BY account_name
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'total_balance' in 'field list'

Comment: i have make a new column total_balance i think so

Comment: Is this column already in your table or is the second one from your query? If you are trying to get a sum of sums then this is not the way to do it.